# Dealing with different date formats in python

Tags: python, csv, date, datetime-parsing

So I have a issue around dates that are coming from a excel sheet which I'm transforming into a CSV and then loading into a data frame. Basically the data I'm dealing with each day can come in two different formats. These two date columns are called `Appointment Date` and `Attended Date`

I'm dealing with (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM) and (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM) and its coming from a third party so I cant set the date format structure. What i need to do is parse the data and remove the HH:MM and output the data only has DD/MM/YYYY.

My current code is currently the following:

```
df['Appointment Date'] = df['Appointment Date'].str.replace(' ', '/', regex=True)
df['Attended Date'] = df['Attended Date'].str.replace(' ', '/', regex=True)
df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
df['Attended Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Attended Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

But I'm not able to parse the data when it comes through as YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
Exception error:

```
time data '2021-10-08/00:00:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M' (match)
```

Any ideas on how i can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it one way, and if it doesn't work, try it the other way.

```
try:
    df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
except WhateverDateParseException:
    df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'], format="%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Of course, instead of `WhateverDateParseException` use the actual exception that is raised in your code.

*Edit: fixed missing "%S"*

Comment: So i wrote this

 `def change_date_time():
       try:
        df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    except TypeError:
        df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'],
format="%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

but I'm still getting the error `ValueError: time data '2021-10-08/00:00:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M' (match)` and `TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>`

Answer (score 2):

I would use regular expressions for that as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"daytime": ["31/12/2020 23:59", "2020/12/31 23:59"]})
df["daypart"] = df["daytime"].str.replace(r" \d\d:\d\d","")  # drop HH:MM part
df["day"] = df["daypart"].str.replace(r"(\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d)", r"\3/\2/\1")
print(df)
```

output

```
            daytime     daypart         day
0  31/12/2020 23:59  31/12/2020  31/12/2020
1  2020/12/31 23:59  2020/12/31  31/12/2020
```

Explanation: I used so-called capturing groups in second `.replace`, if there is (4 digits)/(2 digits)/(2 digits) their order is re-arranged that 3rd become 1st, 2nd become 2nd and 1st become 3rd (note that group are 1-based, not 0-base like is case with general `python` indexing). AS `day` format is now consistent you could be able to parse it easily.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @C14L that method can be followed but my guess seeing your exception is you need to add a seconds format (%S) to your time formatting, so the updated code wld be like

```
try:
    df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
except WhateverDateParseException:
    df['Appointment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment Date'], format="%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

The format, `%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M` does not match with the Date-Time string, `2021-10-08/00:00:00`. You need to use `%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S` for this Date-Time string.

**Demo:**

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = '2021-10-08/00:00:00'
date_str = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(date_str)
```

**Output:**

```
08/10/2021
```